# PHP mailer cant send email without attachment

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

im newbie using PHPmailer, I'm trying to send an email and everything is work fine if all input in form is filled.

but I can't send an email if attachment is empty.
please help me how can I send an email without attachment or make the attachment is optional.
here is my code :
[php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anYxb.jpg)

and this is my form 
[form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5e947.jpg)

thank u.

Comment: Please post your code in the question instead of attaching screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not pass any file and you call the function move_uploaded_file it returns false. So sendmail will not be called. You made the file upload addictive to the sendmail

## EDIT

Try something like that:

```
if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['attachment']['name'], $file)) { 
$file = false; 
 } 
sendmail($to, $subjects, $body, $file);
```

Then you can say:

```
if($attachment) { 
$mail->addAttachment($attachment); 
}
```

Sorry for bad code formatting, wrote it on my mobile phone

Comment: this is work !! 
thank u very much sir.

Comment: No problem. Please mark this post as answere if it helped you

Comment: You didn't show how `$attachment` is defined.

Comment: `$attachment` is a required parameter in the function `sendmail()` If you look above we pass `$file` as fourth parameter to the function `sendmail` and if you watch the code posted by budi as image it says: `function sendmail($to, $subject, $body, $attachment) { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

Just do not write

```
$mail->addAttachment(...
```

if there is no file.

For example

```
if ($_FILES['attachemnt']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    $mail->addAttachment(...
}
```

Comment: where i can add that condition sir ?
thank u so much.

Comment: Please, post you code, so I can change it.

Answer (score 1):

Base on your question, more specifically

> everything is work fine **if all input in form is filled**

You just need to remove check on attachment `input` field inside your `JavaScript`

If that is already handled, than I'll suggest to put a check if attachment file is present or not, inside `sendemail` function of your `php` file; if no, than do not add `$mail->addAttachment` like `Ivan Bolnikh` has suggested or use

```
if(isset($attachment))
    $mail->addAttachment($attachment);
```

Hope it helps!!!